# Cassandra Output issue using Pentaho

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, etl

I have been following this link to add data to Cassandra from a file (http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/BAD/Write+Data+To+Cassandra). The transformation seems to be working fine, but there are no rows inserted in Cassandra column family. Please suggest what could be the workaround. The screenshot may clarify the issue. Thanks

[cassandra output step configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHOtM.png)

Comment: Zohaa, that seems weird. Let me try to help you.

Can you post the screenshot with Cassandra output step configurations?

Have you tried downloading the example from that tutorial? Does it work for you?

Abou your PDI version, have you consideraded upgrading to 6.1 or at least 5.4?

Comment: I have downloaded the ktr from the given link. The results have been posted in screenshot 1. All works well without any errors, but the results are not being stored in column family as get returns 0 rows. I have been using pdi 5.2.0.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KHOtM.png cassandra output step configurations

Comment: Havê you testes a newer PDI version? Maybe it's a fixed bug.

Comment: I have tried the same with pdi 5.4, but the issue is still the same, transformation executing without errors, but no records in my column family. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In write option properties enable use CQL version 3 ..
that will solve your problem.

Comment: I am using cassandra 2.2.5 and pentaho 5.4. I am unable to connect to my cassandra keyspace. I get the following error: Refused to connect.

Comment: because pentaho doesn't support new versions of cassandra.
you can use 2.0.11 or lesser versions. like 1.2.8 ...
2.1 onward cassandra changes the architecture and that is not yet implemented by pentaho.